# How to pass gradle.properties key/value pairs into JUnit test when clicking VSCode "Run Test" codelens

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

We set several key/value pairs in our gradle.properties file. (eg `LOGIN_UID`, `LOGIN_PWD`)

We can successfully reference them in our build.gradle (eg `$LOGIN_UID`) and our JUnit tests (eg `System.getProperty("LOGIN_UID")` when running `gradle test` from the cmdline.

However when clicking on a `Run Test` codelens within a JUnit's Java file within VSCode gradle.properties are not passed in.  Guessing the Gradle `test` task is not being executed?

Greatly appreciate it if someone can help us understand and solve this running from a codelens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need is to add a setting in VS Code, something like this:

```
{
    "java.test.config": {
        "vmArgs": ["-DLOGIN_UID=id", ...]
    }
}
```

Then test runner will pick up them and pass the properties to JVM.

At last, the configuration can be persisted in your workspace's `.vscode/settings.json`. If the properties have any sensitive data, like password, don't commit them to the source control!

Comment: Thank you Sheng.  This will definitely work.  I was really hoping to avoid additional setup and somehow have VSCode detect what's in my gradle.properties.

Comment: Yes, I believe we can address this issue once we support delegate testing to Gradle tooling: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1045